# Scala: Why the Int type list contains String as well?

Tags: scala, generics

```
val wordList = List("I", "want", "to", "learn", "scala")
val wordSizeList = list.map(x=>x.length)
def func[A, B](a:List[A]):List[B]={
  a.collect({case x:B => x})
}

val result = func[Any, Int](wordList ::: wordSizeList)
```

Below is the worksheet result

```
wordList: List[String] = List(I, want, to, learn, scala)
wordSizeList: List[Int] = List(1, 4, 2, 5, 5)
func: [A, B](a: List[A])List[B]

result: List[Int] = List(I, want, to, learn, scala, 1, 4, 2, 5, 5)
```

why doesn't it filter based on the Generic type "B"?
And if you see the result list, how can a Int type list can contain String as well?

Comment: scala compiler gives you warning if you run with `sbt` or `repl` `warning: abstract type pattern B is unchecked since it is eliminated by erasure
  a.collect({case x:B => x})`

Answer (score 6):

Looks to me a type erasure problem, which can be remedied with a [`ClassTag`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.0/scala/reflect/ClassTag.html):

```
import scala.reflect.ClassTag

def func[A, B : ClassTag](a: List[A]): List[B] = {
  a.collect{ case x: B => x }
}

val result = func[Any, Int](wordList ::: wordSizeList)
// result: List[Int] = List(1, 4, 2, 5, 5)
```